# Different results for covariance matrix when using numpy.cov

Tags: python, numpy

I can't figure out why I am getting a different covariance matrix when using np.cov:

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.random((10,3))
b = a - np.mean(a,axis=0,keepdims=True)

print "np.cov(a.T):"
print tabulate(np.cov(a.T),floatfmt='.2f',tablefmt='grid')
print "\nnp.dot(b.T,b):"
print tabulate(np.dot(b.T,b),floatfmt='.2f',tablefmt='grid')
```

output:

```
np.cov(a.T):
+-------+-------+-------+
|  0.10 |  0.03 | -0.01 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  0.03 |  0.08 | -0.07 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| -0.01 | -0.07 |  0.12 |
+-------+-------+-------+

np.dot(b.T,b):
+-------+-------+-------+
|  0.92 |  0.26 | -0.09 |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  0.26 |  0.72 | -0.60 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| -0.09 | -0.60 |  1.07 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Any idea why the results are different? What formula numpy uses for covariance calculations?

UPDATE:
I wasn't normalizing my covariance equation above, using (N-1) as suggested in the comments fixed the issue in this case. 
However, I noticed that in my real example, I am getting slightly different results using np.cov. Seems like if I save my input data using np.savetxt versus np.save, I get different results:

```
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

a1 = np.load('d1.npy')[:,0:3]
print "np.loadtxt:"
print tabulate(a1,floatfmt='.20f',tablefmt='grid')

a2 = np.loadtxt('/d1.txt')[:,0:3]
print "\nload:"
print tabulate(a2,floatfmt='.20f',tablefmt='grid')

b1 = a1 - np.mean(a1,axis=0,keepdims=True)
b2 = a2 - np.mean(a2,axis=0,keepdims=True)

print "\nnp.cov(a1.T):"
print tabulate(np.cov(a1.T),floatfmt='.14f',tablefmt='grid')

print "\nnp.dot(b1.T,b):"
print tabulate(np.dot(b1.T,b1)/float(len(b1)-1),floatfmt='.14f',tablefmt='grid')

print "\nnp.cov(a2.T):"
print tabulate(np.cov(a2.T),floatfmt='.14f',tablefmt='grid')

print "\nnp.dot(b2.T,b):"
print   tabulate(np.dot(b2.T,b2)/float(len(b2)-1),floatfmt='.14f',tablefmt='grid')
```

output:

```
np.loadtxt:
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12400000542402267456     | 0.29300001263618469238     | 0.08000000566244125366     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12300000339746475220     | 0.28900000452995300293     | 0.06900000572204589844     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13800001144409179688     | 0.28100001811981201172     | 0.07400000095367431641     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13300000131130218506     | 0.26200002431869506836     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13800001144409179688     | 0.27900001406669616699     | 0.06700000166893005371     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12900000810623168945     | 0.26100000739097595215     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12700000405311584473     | 0.25600001215934753418     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12700000405311584473     | 0.26200002431869506836     | 0.08200000226497650146     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12400000542402267456     | 0.28000000119209289551     | 0.07300000637769699097     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12600000202655792236     | 0.30200001597404479980     | 0.06599999964237213135     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+

np.load:
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12400000542402267456     | 0.29300001263618469238     | 0.08000000566244125366     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12300000339746475220     | 0.28900000452995300293     | 0.06900000572204589844     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13800001144409179688     | 0.28100001811981201172     | 0.07400000095367431641     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13300000131130218506     | 0.26200002431869506836     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.13800001144409179688     | 0.27900001406669616699     | 0.06700000166893005371     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12900000810623168945     | 0.26100000739097595215     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12700000405311584473     | 0.25600001215934753418     | 0.07700000703334808350     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12700000405311584473     | 0.26200002431869506836     | 0.08200000226497650146     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12400000542402267456     | 0.28000000119209289551     | 0.07300000637769699097     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+
| 0.12600000202655792236     | 0.30200001597404479980     | 0.06599999964237213135     |
+------------------------    +------------------------    +------------------------+

np.cov(a1.T):
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
|  0.00003121113778     | -0.00001961109117     | -0.00000486667563     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00001961109117     |  0.00024427771650     | -0.00005066667516     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00000486667563     | -0.00005066667516     |  0.00002951112509     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+

np.dot(b1.T,b):
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
|  0.00003121113696     | -0.00001961109228     | -0.00000486667523     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00001961109228     |  0.00024427770404     | -0.00005066667654     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00000486667523     | -0.00005066667654     |  0.00002951112219     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+

np.cov(a2.T):
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
|  0.00003121113778     | -0.00001961109117     | -0.00000486667563     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00001961109117     |  0.00024427771650     | -0.00005066667516     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00000486667563     | -0.00005066667516     |  0.00002951112509     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+

np.dot(b2.T,b):
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
|  0.00003121113778     | -0.00001961109117     | -0.00000486667563     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00001961109117     |  0.00024427771650     | -0.00005066667516     |
+-------------------    +-------------------    +-------------------+
| -0.00000486667563     | -0.00005066667516     |  0.00002951112509     |
```

As you can see the results of `np.dot(b1.T,b)` are slightly different.

Comment: You should divide the dot product by `N-1` and then you get the same result. You are missing the normalization. Look at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, something is still not correct. Please see below.

Comment: This is yet another thing you should look up, floating point error. Float numbers are never exact.

Comment: But how come when I print the data, they are identical up to 20 decimal point, but after calculations they differ after only 11 decimal point. And only in some cases they differ, not all cases. My guess is that underlying calculations/equations are different and I am trying to find where this is originating.